# Page numbering appearing in the wrong place

Tags: page-numbering

My list of figures spans two pages, and on the first page, it is appearing at the bottom center, and on the next page, it is appearing on the bottom right. I want it to be on the bottom right on the first page where the list of figures starts. How do I set this right?

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[top=1.0in,bottom=0.75in,left=1.25in,right=1in]{geometry} %Margins
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=back,citecolor = black]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{Figure \hspace{1.3mm}}

\begin{document}

\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\rhead{}
\rfoot{}
\rhead{}
\rfoot{}
\lhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Pg.No}\par}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\afterpage{~\hfill\textbf{Pg.No}\par\medskip}} 

\clearpage

\rfoot{\thepage}
\pagenumbering{roman}
 \listoffigures
 \thispagestyle{fancy}
  \rhead{}
  \lhead{}
  \lfoot{}
 \cfoot{}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
\addtocontents{lof}{~\hfill\textbf{Pg.No}\par}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}  

\chapter{Test title}
    Dummy text.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to redefine the pagestyle with `\fancypagestyle` instead of just changing it for a single page with `\thispagestyle` , i.e.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
  \rfoot{\thepage}}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test title}
Dummy text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for our prompt reply. I did change it from '\thispagestyle' to '\pagestyle', but there is no change.

Comment: @user1556826 I added an example code

Comment: I'm getting an error saying the .aux file can't be opened.

Comment: @user1556826 Try deleting all your `.aux`, `.log`, `.out`, `.toc` and `.lof` files before compiling. The code above compiles without any issue on my computer.

Comment: No, it was a problem with my PDF file. I set it right, and it works perfectly. Thank you!!